# Hibernate(HQL) - how to query "where many in()" many to many

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, where-in

I have a user entity that has many cars.
I cant fetch the user by car list with "IN" statement.

```
List<Car> cars = getCarsList();
String hql = "From User WHERE user.cars in(:cars)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
query.setParameterList("cars",cars);
//query.setParameterList("cars",cars.toArray());//not working also
//query.setParameter("cars","1,4,8,30");//not working also
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

In this way, the parameter is cars being  ignored.
I have also tries to send vars.toArray();
And I also tried to send String 1,4,8,300 (Ids if cars).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user alias is not defined. Try with

```
String hql = "from User user inner join user.cars car where car.id in (:carIds)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
query.setParameterList("cars", carIds);
```

where carIds is a collection (and not a string  as in your third try) containing the IDs of the cars.

Comment: Thanks, But I want to avoid using "Joins", isn't that what hibernate is all about? User is already fetching the cars since it is in ManyToMany relations.

Comment: BTW, carIds means List<Car> or (0,5,100)?

Comment: as I said, carIds is a collection (as in java.util.Collection) containing the IDs of the cars. So if Integer is the type of the ID of the Car entity, a List<Integer> is OK (although a Set<Integer> is more logical in this case). And fetching has nothing to do with this question. Joins are the appropriate way to navigate through associations between entities in HQL.

Comment: So if it wasn't a many-to-many I wouldnt need the join? as I say in your home page.

Comment: Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins. You may chain properties as long as they reference a XxxToOne association : person.parent.name is OK, but person.children.name is not.